# Rage spell on healers?

Tags: clash-of-clans

What if I use rage spell on healers healing the queen? Will they heal more?

I can test this but I dont want to waste any elixir, so if anybody know the answer, please let me know?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, using a rage spell on healers will make them heal their target faster. It is a common strategy to use rage spells on the healers and the Queen when doing a queen walk, as it will allow the queen to survive getting hit from multiple defenses.

Comment: And heal spell on healers? Does that help too?

Comment: @BhaskarVashishth it will help them stay alive longer if they are taking damage and the hewing will stack.